# How to connect Activity and Fragment when creating activity(Android)

Tags: java, android

I created an android project using the **Bottom Navigation Activity template**, but I found it difficult to connect Activity and Fragment. For example, when a activity star the MainActivity, and there's a textView in the HomeFragment, I want to set the text in the onCreate() func in MainActivity. I've try

```java
((TextView) binding.getRoot().getViewById(R.id.textView)).setText(test);
```

but it seems the Fragment not be created yet so I get null pointer.
The project structure and the MainActivity Class as follow,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTi1Q.png)
The textView is a View id in navigation_home
I am new in android development, thks.

The way to connect the Activity and the Fragment in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't use `BottomNavigationActivity`, but you normally use controls (such as your `textView`) inside the `Fragment` itself (eg. in the `onViewCreated` method after inflation of the according layout). Take a look at [this post](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Creating-and-Using-Fragments).
Probably that's the reason, why it's not inflated, because you did not do it in the `Fragment`.

To communicate between `Fragments` and/or `Activity` you can use `ViewModels`. You define a `ViewModel` for the Activity and get it in the Fragment with

```
new ViewModelProvider(getActivity()).get(YourModel.class)
```

In the ViewModel itself it's best do define `(Mutable)LiveData<>` and observe it. So whenever you change the data, you are notified, plus you don't need to worry about the fragment state. LiveData checks, whether your fragment still exists and removes it from the list of observers when it's destroyed.

Within the

Comment: Thks!!!! U help me a lot. I solved the communication problem by using LiveData and ViewModel.